# Cannot access class __init__ variable from one file to another for code that is split into two different files (python)

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

Let's say I have two files: `code_for_gui.py` and `code_for_functions.py`,

in my `code_for_gui.py` I have a class:

```
Class Main_screen_one():
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
          Main_screen_one.button_choice = tk.IntVar()
```

and I have a separate classless function called `begin_process()` and begin_process does something very trivial like:

```
import code_for_gui.py

def begin_process():
     print(code_for_gui.Main_screen_one.button_choice.get())
```

*.get() is a tk function to retrieve a value from a user input device (e.g. radio buttons)*

When I placed begin_process() in `code_for_functions.py` I got an Attribute Error stating that `button_choice` is not an attribute of `Main_screen_one`, I then tried to change the code to have it as:

```
def begin_process():
     print(code_for_gui.Main_screen_one().button_choice.get())
```

including the paranthesis in `Main_screen_one()`, but then I got another error about not enough parameters being passed as it expected the parent and controller too. So I realize this is wrong, but I'm not entirely sure why?

HOWEVER, when I place `begin_process()` into `code_for_gui.py` where  `Class Main_screen_one()` is, I no longer get an error and it works just fine. Can someone please explain why this behavior is happening and where I can potentially read more on this to understand better?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is here (ignoring the obvious syntax error):

```
Class Main_screen_one():
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
          Main_screen_one.button_choice = tk.IntVar()
```

You're setting `button_choice` on the class rather than the instance of the class. It needs to be this:

```
self.button_choice = tk.IntVar()
```

The second problem is where you reference it here:

```
def begin_process():
     print(code_for_gui.Main_screen_one.button_choice.get())
```

You should be accessing the attribute on an instance of a class. That means that somewhere you first need to create an instance, and then use the instance to access the variable:

```
code_for_gui.ms1 = Main_screen_one(...)
...
print(code_for_gui.ms1.button_choice.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the class in the `code_for_functions.py` file? That's why you cannot access the variables defined in the `__init__()` function. I would have commented but i don't have the rep to do so.